# Function error 'expected expression before char'?

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors

I have created the following program which allows a user to guess a word 3 times before ending the program. I'm using a function to read the users input. When I compile the program I get the error 'expected expression before char'. Some feedback would be great thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void get_user_input(char *guess[10]);

void get_user_input(char *guess[10])
{ 
     printf("Please guess the word: \n");
     scanf("%s", guess);
}

int main(void)
{
     const char secret[10] = "pink";
     char guess[10];
     int i;

     for (i=0; i < 3; i++)
     {
         get_user_input(char *guess[10]);

         if (strcmp(secret, guess)==0)
         {
             printf("Your guess was correct");
             return 0;
         }
         else
         {
             printf("Your guess was incorrect. Please try again\n");
         }
     } 
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra `char` here:

```
for (i=0; i < 3; i++)
{
    get_user_input(char *guess[10]);
```

Just get rid of it. You just need to pass the variable in.

```
get_user_input(guess);
```

**EDIT :**

The other problem seems to be this function:

```
void get_user_input(char *guess[10]);
```

change it to this:

```
void get_user_input(char *guess)
{ 
 printf("Please guess the word: \n");
 scanf("%s", guess);
}
```

and it should work. However, be aware that you run the risk of overrunning your `guess` array.

Comment: I tried that earlier and got the following error: passing argument 1 of 'get user input from incompatible pointer type. note expected 'char**' but argument is not of type 'char*'

Comment: Thank you that was a big help! I understand the error too so won't make it again. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Inside the loop, write

```
get_user_input(guess);
```

instead of

```
get_user_input(char *guess[10]);
```

.

In addition, you should delete the useless prototype

```
void get_user_input(char *guess[10]);
```

and change the following function's signature to

```
void get_user_input(char * guess)
```

to let a pointer to the first char of the array be passed instead of a pointer to a pointer to the first char which will not compile. A side issue is that `char *guess[10]` means an array of 10 pointers to char.

PS: It helps to post the offending line number in addition to the error message.

PPS: You have a buffer overrun memory error if the use enters long answers. You can use [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) to avoid this.

Comment: Same as my comment to mystical above Peter thank you very much